# Lightning - Refresh Component on Submit

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have built a lightning app containing 2 components.

1)Comp1 is the login page. Comp2 is the registration page.
2) After logging in user is taken to the registration page. User enters data here that goes into salesforce.

I want to -

1) To Show the progress while the record is being saved.
2) Refresh the page once data is saved.

I tried using  $A.get("e.force:refreshView") but I am getting error as this event is being returned as null. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Events like **$A.get("e.force:refreshView")** are only available in the context of Salesforce1 application.
If you are not running inside SF1 then you have to use standard javascript means, like **window.location.reload()** or **window.location.href = ...**

Comment: Thanks gaiser. Can you please explain what do you mean by **in the context of Salesforce1 application**? Is that a separate framework you are talking about?  **window.location.reload()** does reload the page but it takes me back to the login page. I want my current component i.e. registration page to be shown. How can I get my current component to refresh?

Comment: **context of Salesforce1 application** means that your component/app is running inside Salesforce1, not normal salesforce.
With regards to window.location.reload() - this may be specific to how you implemented your lightning App. I used this approach before (in a standalone app, not in Salesforce1) and it worked as expected.
Try using window.location.href instead, to see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and found what I think is a better solution.

If you have a component that is rendering a cell for a single object, and you want to do things like dynamically getting an icon, or some other call, then re-render once it's returned (which I think is a pretty common thing), you can simply wrap the entire cell in an `<aura:iteration>` tag.

Your component might look like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="render_list" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Object" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.render_list}" var="render" indexVar="indx">
 {!v.item.name}
</aura:iteration>
```

And your callback code might do this:

```
var item = component.get("v.item");
var render_list = [item];
component.set("v.render_list", render_list);
```

This is taking advantage of `<aura:iteration>` being aware that it needs to re-render it's contents on change. Much easier to control what happens and localize where a re-render needs to happen at an object level.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your apps in Lightning Experience or not?
You can follow this link for more info about using force:refreshView:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm